# how to insert data into std::map and show data from std::map in vc6

Tags: c++, mfc

i am using vc6. what is wrong in code below, i cant find out:

```
std::map<int, std::vector<int> > myTemplate; 

//append data to map
int temp=0;
for (int i=0;i<=5;i++)
{
    std::vector<int> tempVector;
    temp+=111;
    tempVector.push_back(temp);
    std::pair<int, std::vector<int> > myPair;
    myPair=std::make_pair(i,tempVector);
    myTemplate.insert(myPair);
}

//show data from map
std::map<int, std::vector<int> >::iterator iter;
iter=myTemplate.begin();
while(iter!=myTemplate.end());
{
    std::vector<int> tempVector;
    std::vector<int>::iterator sencondIter=iter->second.begin();
    int myValue=*sencondIter;
    CString cstrTemp;
    cstrTemp.Format("%d is the int type value in vector<int>",myValue);
    AfxMessageBox(cstrTemp);

    iter++;
}
```

Comment: Don't use Visual C++ 6. It's not standards compliant. Not even any of Microsoft's standards post-Microsoft-Bob.

Comment: It's true, but its still the best IDE that MS have released. All versions released since are inferior.

Comment: Seriously, where does this nonsense about the best IDE come from?

Answer (score 8):

Semicolon after `while` results in an infinite loop

```
while(iter!=myTemplate.end()); // <-----------------------
```

Remove it.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you check out Microsoft Visual Studio Express here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express

For updated versions of MS Visual Studio IDEs